# Why does my POST request (HTTPS) request fail?

Tags: java, post

I am trying to make an auto login program for my schools wifi login system. I need to do a POST request to a the authentication URL (https://ccahack.bergen.org/auth/perfigo_validate.jsp) and submit some parameters.If I change the HTTPS to a HTTP and do the POST request it just redirects me back to the sign in forum. So it is imperative that I POST to the HTTPS, but the problem is that I get an SSL socket error, here is my code:

```
public boolean signIn() throws Exception{
        //System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");
        String httpsURL = "https://ccahack.bergen.org/auth/perfigo_validate.jsp";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
        q.append("reqFrom="+URLEncoder.encode("perfigo_simple_login.jsp","UTF-8")); 
        q.append("&uri="+ URLEncoder.encode("https://ccahack.bergen.org/","UTF-8"));
        q.append("&cm=" + URLEncoder.encode("ws32vklm", "UTF-8"));
        q.append("&userip="+URLEncoder.encode("IP_ADDRESS HERE","UTF-8"));
        q.append("&os=" +URLEncoder.encode("MAC_OSX","UTF-8"));
        q.append("&index="+URLEncoder.encode("4","UTF-8"));
        q.append("&username="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8"));
        q.append("&password="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8"));
        q.append("&provider="+URLEncoder.encode("BCA","UTF-8"));
        q.append("&login_submt="+URLEncoder.encode("Continue","UTF8"));
        String query = q.toString();
        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length())); 
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)"); 
        con.setDoOutput(true); 
        con.setDoInput(true); 

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  
            //error here

        output.writeBytes(query);

        output.close();

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() ); 



        for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() ) 
        System.out.print( (char)c ); 
        input.close(); 

        System.out.println("Resp Code:"+con.getResponseCode()); 
        System.out.println("Resp Message:"+ con.getResponseMessage()); 
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It will help if you post the error.

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception you posted in the comment, you will need to ensure that the site's certificate is in your truststore. (Assuming here that you trust it.)

Here'e something I wrote up some time back:

http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/29/fixing-pkix-path-building-issues-when-using-javamail-and-smtp/

In this case I was doing SMTP (where you are doing HTTP) so you will need to make adjustments for that.

Comment: I am little confused on what to do. I understand that I need to download the certificate but what command do I use? Something like this?:
openssl s_client -connect mail.kattare.com:2525https://ccahack.bergen.org/auth/perfigo_validate.jsp:80 -htpp http > bergen.cer